# VBA macro to clean scraped data not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large data and unformatted quantity of data I have scraped from the web. I am now trying to right some vba to transform this stuff into usable data.

The raw data is structured as follows in excel:

```
1. Centre hospitalier René Dubos (Pontoise)


Capacité totale : 1048 places
Type de structure : CH (Centre Hospitalier)
Dépend de : Centre Hospitalier René Dubos (Pontoise)
Centre hospitalier René Dubos
Adresse : 6, avenue de L'Ile de France 95303 Pontoise

2. Groupement hospitalier Eaubonne - Montmorency - Hôpital Simone Veil (MONTMO...  B


Capacité totale : 916 places
Type de structure : CH (Centre Hospitalier)
Dépend de : Groupement hospitalier Eaubonne - Montmorency (Hôpital Simone Veil) (MONTMORENCY)
Groupement hospitalier Eaubonne - Montmorency - Hôpital Simone Veil
Adresse : 1, rue Jean Moulin 95160 MONTMORENCY

3. Centre Hospitalier de Gonesse (Gonesse)  C


Capacité totale : 878 places
Type de structure : CH (Centre Hospitalier)
Dépend de : Centre Hospitalier de Gonesse (Gonesse)
Centre Hospitalier de Gonesse 
Adresse : 25 rue Bernard Février 95503 Gonesse
```

etc...

I'm trying to do the following:

If the cell starts with a number, then this should go in the first column of a table in another worksheet.
Then, I'd like to enter each line that corresponds to "capacite totale" , "type de structure", "depend de" and "address" in seperate columns but on the same row where we have copied the cell starting by a number (i.e. 1.).

There are about 300 worksheets in a single workbook, so I was thinking that the code should loop through all the worksheet, look at the first characters of each cell and then put it in a specific column in another single main worksheet.

Unfortunately I'm just starting with VBA, and although I got the **scraper** to work, I'm not having much luck with macros.

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub cleaning_data()

' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
 Dim Current As Worksheet

 ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
 For Each Current In Worksheets

    For x = 1 To 150
        If IsEmpty(Cells(x, 1)) Then
            x = x + 1
        Else
            x = x + 1
        End If
        
        'Is it a title
        If IsNumeric(Left(Cells(x, 1), 1)) Then
            ' Copy cell and put it as first entry in table
            Cells(x, 1).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Select
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Paste
            x = x + 1
        
         'Is it capacity
         ElseIf Left(Cells(x, 1), 2) = "Ca" Then
             Cells(x, 1).Copy
             'paste in column 2
             Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Paste
             x = x + 1
             
        'Is it type
         ElseIf Left(Cells(x, 1), 2) = "Ty" Then
             Cells(x, 1).Copy
             'paste where column 3
             Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Paste
             x = x + 1
             
         'Is it what it depends of
         ElseIf Left(Cells(x, 1), 2) = "Dé" Then
             Cells(x, 1).Copy
             Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 4).Paste
             'paste where appropriate
             x = x + 1
            
             
         'Is it the address
         ElseIf Left(Cells(x, 1), 2) = "Ad" Then
             Cells(x, 1).Copy
             'paste where appropriate
             Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 5).Paste
             x = x + 1
        End If
    Next x
    Next
        
End Sub
```

Would anyone have thoughts as to how I could fix this code?

Thank you!

Comment: what is **not working**?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: runtime 1004 select method of range class failed.

Comment: you need to qualify your Cells object, add `current.Cells...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want this, like a Transpose using Pure VBA:

```
Sub sof20327437CleanData()

  Dim i As Long, iRow As Long, iCol As Long
  Dim x
  Dim strLine
  ' Declare wksDest as a worksheet object variable.
  Dim wksDest As Worksheet
  ' Declare wksCurrent as a worksheet object variable.
  Dim wksCurrent As Worksheet

  '
  iRow = 1
  Set wksDest = Sheets("Sheet1")
  wksDest.UsedRange.Clear
 '
  wksDest.Cells(1, 1) = "No."
  wksDest.Cells(1, 2) = "Capacité totale"
  wksDest.Cells(1, 3) = "Type de structure"
  wksDest.Cells(1, 4) = "Dépend de"
  wksDest.Cells(1, 5) = "Adresse"


  ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
  For Each wksCurrent In Worksheets

    iCol = 0
    'Set wksCurrent = ActiveSheet

    For x = 1 To 150

      ' by strLine to gain CPU, a small RAM instead to each time accessing the Cell:
      '
      strLine = Trim(wksCurrent.Cells(x, 1))

      ' skip empty line:
      If (Not IsEmpty(strLine)) Then

        'Is it a title
        If IsNumeric(Left(strLine, 1)) Then
          iCol = 1
          iRow = iRow + 1

        'Is it capacity
        ElseIf (InStr(1, strLine, "Capacit", vbTextCompare) = 1) Then
          iCol = 2

        'Is it type
        ElseIf (InStr(1, strLine, "Type", vbTextCompare) = 1) Then
          iCol = 3

        'Is it what it depends of
        ElseIf (InStr(1, strLine, "Dépend", vbTextCompare) = 1) Then
          iCol = 4

        'Is it the address
        ElseIf (InStr(1, strLine, "Adresse", vbTextCompare) = 1) Then
          iCol = 5
        End If

        If (iCol > 0) Then
          If (iCol >= 2) Then
            ' cut useless info like Adresse :
            i = InStr(1, strLine, ":", vbTextCompare)
            If (i > 0) Then
              strLine = Mid(strLine, i + 2)
            End If
          End If
          ' we concat string, as Dépende can have some lines:
          If (Not IsEmpty(wksDest.Cells(iRow, iCol))) Then
            strLine = " " & strLine
          End If
          wksDest.Cells(iRow, iCol) = wksDest.Cells(iRow, iCol) & strLine
        End If

      End If
    Next
    '
    'Exit For
    '
  Next
'
  Set wksDest = Nothing
  Set wksCurrent = Nothing
'
End Sub
```

It gets this:

[image]